# Update Phone Number in Firebase Authentication - React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I have a screen it's a settings screen and I have an input that's for update data,

so I want to update the signed phone number how can I achieve it?
**and how did I get the credential?**

here's my code
I used react-native-firebase v6+

```js
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

const updateMobile = async () => {
  await auth().currentUser.updatePhoneNumber((credential) =>
    console.log(credential)
  );
};
```

When I call this function I got this error

> Attempt to invoke virtual method "boolean
> java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)" on an null object referance

UPDATE

I read a Docs and I get the credential like this, But I have an error, I don't know who's bind -_-

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 2): TypeError: Cannot read
> property 'bind' of undefined

=====

When i delete `await` in `const snapshot = auth().verifyPhoneNumber(mobile)` the error go away but i see a new error

> Error: [auth/invalid-credential] The supplied auth credential
> is malformed, has expired, or is not currently supported.

```js
const updateMobile = async () => {
  const snapshot = await auth()
    .verifyPhoneNumber(mobile)
    .on('state_changed', (phoneAuthSnapshot) => {
      console.log('Snapshot state: ', phoneAuthSnapshot.state);
    });
  const credential = auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
    snapshot.verificationId,
    snapshot.code
  );
  console.log('credential', credential);
  await auth().currentUser.updatePhoneNumber(credential);
};
```

Comment: after calling `verifyphonenumber` are you getting a code on your phone?

Comment: Never, It should send code to me if i use debugging version of my app? @PeterHaddad

Comment: @PeterHaddad Any help?

Comment: I am facing the same problem.